# Switching from Android Camera API to Camera2 API

Tags: android, android-camera, android-service, android-camera2

I'm using a tablet running Android 5.1. I have implemented a service using the `Camera` API for recording the front cam in the background. The code is shown below. Now I would like to change it to `Camera2` API. In addition I would like to manually set the apperture and the exposure time (which is only possible with `Camera2` API but not `Camera` API I think). How can I adapt my code?

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.media.CamcorderProfile;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import inf.ethz.ch.affectivestudy.MainActivity;

public class RecorderService extends Service implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    private Camera camera = null;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        windowManager = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        surfaceView = new SurfaceView(this);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                1, 1,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );
        layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        windowManager.addView(surfaceView, layoutParams);
        surfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                notificationIntent, 0);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                //.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.app_icon)
                .setContentTitle("Background Video Recorder")
                .setContentText("")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent).build();

        startForeground(MainActivity.NOTIFICATION_ID_RECORDER_SERVICE, notification);

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        camera = Camera.open(1);
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));

        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/storage/emulated/0/Study/Camera/test.mp4");

        try { mediaRecorder.prepare(); } catch (Exception ignored) {}
        mediaRecorder.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        mediaRecorder.reset();
        mediaRecorder.release();

        camera.lock();
        camera.release();

        windowManager.removeView(surfaceView);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format, int width, int height) {}

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {}

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) { return null; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera2 is quite different, so adapting is not straightforward.

I'd recommend you look at Google's sample apps, especially [Camera2Video](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video), to see how to do recording with camera2.

Once you have that running, you can look at using manual controls on devices that support it (have capability MANUAL_SENSOR); though note that very few phones actually have a variable aperture.